# equivalent code of Or command in vb.net

Tags: c#, vb.net

I want to learn how can I use Or command (VB.NET) in C#?

I have an example:

```
foundCommand = _applicationObject.Commands.AddNamedCommand(_addInInstance, name, name, caption, _
                                True, iconID, Nothing, vsCommandStatus.vsCommandStatusSupported Or vsCommandStatus.vsCommandStatusEnabled)
```

I want to use vsCommandStatus.vsCommandStatusNotSupported Or vsCommandStatus.vsCommandStatusEnabled together in C#.

Comment: @EoinCampbell No, the C# equivalent of the `OR` operator is `|`. The VB.Net equivalent of the C# `||` operator is `OrElse`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the bitwise OR operator `|` to link enum flag values, which is your case.

```
vsCommandStatus.vsCommandStatusSupported | vsCommandStatus.vsCommandStatusEnabled
```

For conditionals or Boolean values, use the logical OR operator `||`.

Comment: @DogukanDemir that's because the `OR` in VB is equivalent to `|` in C#. You can use a `bitwise OR` with bit flags (which in .NET are represented by enums). But with .NET you can only use a `logical OR` between two booleans.

Answer (score 4):

Here is a little table of VB.NET to C# operators:

```
VB.NET     C#
--------   --
And        &
AndAlso    &&
Or         |
OrElse     ||
Xor        ^
Mod        %
Not        !
```